# How to choose organization for orderer?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am curios about how to choose organization for orderer.

Imagine situation in network there is 3 organizations, `Org1`, `Org2`, `Org3`, they have their own peers.

On the other side there is Solo orderer. As we know orderer is peer too, and it needs organization. What should I do when I don't want to create new organization for orderer and I want orderer to be for example under `Org1`. And also in which case should I use different organization for orderer?

Also when I want to deploy project and there is more then 1 orderer peers. what is best practice to create ordering system for channel?

Answer (score 1):

In general you should not allow an organization to act as both an application and orderer. From the [docs](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/ordering-service-faq.html):

> Although this is possible, it is a highly discouraged configuration. By default the `/Channel/Orderer/BlockValidation` policy allows any valid certificate of the ordering organizations to sign blocks. If an organization is acting both in an ordering and application role, then this policy should be updated to restrict block signers to the subset of certificates authorized for ordering.

Essentially if an organization fulfills both roles, then it is possible for any member of that organization to maliciously sign any block and corrupt the ledger. If this is not reason enough to separate them out, you will need to [update your channel configuration](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/config_update.html) so that only specific members of that organization can sign blocks.

Because of the above reasons, the solo orderer is intended for development purposes only. Best practice for deployment (as of v1.3) is to use a [Kafka based ordering service](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/kafka.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have done what you want for my test network. When you configure the configtx.yaml file and create the profile to create the genesis block later on, there you specify the organization for the orderer:

```
MyOrdererGenesis:
      <<: *ChannelDefaults
      Orderer:
          <<: *OrdererDefaults
          Organizations:
              - <<: *Org1


      Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults

            Organizations:
                - <<: *Org1       
                - <<: *Org2 

      Consortiums:

        MyConsortium:

            Organizations:
                  - <<: *Org1                             
                  - <<: *Org2
```

So in your organizations section you will only have Org1 and Org2.